# Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2dx\geq 4$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R} $ be an integrable function with $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=1$.
Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2dx\geq 4$.

I got that $\int_{0}^{1}F(x)dx=F(0)$, but I don't think it's useful at all.

Comment: What is $F$ exactly?

Comment: A primitive of $f$.

Comment: Ah, the last identity doesn't depend on the constant chosen, got it.

Comment: The idea is the following. Pick some constants $a,b$. Then $\int_0^1 (ax+b)f(x)dx=a+b$. Then use Cauchy-schwarz. Choose the constants that give you the inequality you want.

Comment: I obtained the inequality desired. Thank you very much, @Michael. Though, how did you come with the idea to use those constants?

Comment: Well, as soon as I saw that you know $\int f(x) dx$ and you want an inequality for $\int f^2(x) dx$, I knew that you should probably use Cauchy-Schwarz. Also, probably you should use that $\int xf(x)=1$. I think its natural to use the linearity of the integral in order to combine these information and then use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 20):

I would begin with

$$\int_0^1 dx \left [f(x) - (a x+b) \right ]^2 \ge 0 $$

for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.  Expand the integrals and use the info provided to get that

$$\int_0^1 dx \, f(x)^2 \ge 2 a+2 b - \frac13 a^2-a b-b^2 $$

I would then maximize the expression on the right.  Let the expression on the RHS be $g(a,b)$.

We may maximize by taking derivatives of $g(a,b)$ wrt $a$ and $b$ and setting them equal to zero.   We then get a system of equations

$$2 a + 3 b = 6$$
$$a+2 b=2$$

which implies that $a=6$ and $b=-2$. Note that $g_{aa} g_{bb} - g_{ab}^2 = \frac13 \gt 0$ and $g_{aa} = -\frac23 \lt 0$, so the critical point we found is indeed a maximum.  It is then easy to verify that $g(6,-2)=4$.

Answer (score 8):

Observe that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x$ defines an inner product on the space of square-integrable functions on $[0,1].$ If $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^{2}\mathrm{d}x=+\infty,$ then it is certainly at least 4, so we may restrict to this case. Now observe that if $f(x)=a+bx,$ then $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^{2}\mathrm{d}x=a^{2}+ab+b^{2}/3,$ and $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=a+b/2,\quad\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)\mathrm{d}x=a/2+b/3.$$ Now if $f$ is a general square-integrable function, it must be of the form $a+bx+g(x),$ where $g(x)$ is orthogonal to $1$ and $x$ with respect to this inner product, i.e., $\int_{0}^{1}g(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{1}xg(x)\mathrm{d}x=0.$ Then we have that \begin{align*}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^{2}\mathrm{d}x&=\int_{0}^{1}(a+bx)^{2}+2(a+bx)g(x)+g(x)^{2}\mathrm{d}x\\&=\int_{0}^{1}(a+bx)^{2}+g(x)^{2}\mathrm{d}x\\&\geq \int_{0}^{1}(a+bx)^{2}\mathrm{d}x=a^{2}+ab+b^{2}/3.\end{align*}

Solving the system of equations $a+b/2=1,$ $a/2+b/3=1,$ we get that $a=-2$ and $b=6,$ so we have that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^{2}\mathrm{d}x\geq 4.$

Comment: You've made a small mistake..it's $b^2$, not $b^3$...thus you'll obtain the inequality I wanted to prove.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks! I knew something was off...

Answer (score 2):

$Michael 's idea:

$(a+b)^2=\left(\int_0^1(ax+b)f(x)dx\right)^2=T$

We know Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$\left(\int_Df\cdot gdx\right)^2\le \int_Df^2dx\int_Dg^2dx$

We use this inequality:

$(a+b)^2=T\le \int_0^1(f(x))^2dx\int_0^1(ax+b)^2dx$

$\int_0^1(f(x))^2dx\ge \frac{(a+b)^2}{\frac{a^2}{3}+ab+b^2}$

$a=-3b$

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy's inequality $$\displaystyle \left(\sum_{k=n}^m a_k b_k \right)^2 \le \left( \sum_{k=n}^m a_k^2\right) \left(\sum_{k=n}^m b_k^2\right)$$

or $$\left(\int_{n}^m f(x)g(x)dx\right)^2 \le \left(\int_{n}^m f(x)^2dx\right)\left(\int_{n}^m g(x)^2dx\right)$$

So for all real $a$: $$\displaystyle \left(\int_{0}^1 f(x)- ax dx\right)^2 \le \left(\int_{0}^1 1dx\right)\left(\int_{0}^1 (f(x)- ax)^2 dx\right)$$

$$\left(1- \frac a 2\right)^2 \le \int_{0}^1 f(x)^2dx -2a\int_{0}^1xf(x)dx +  a^2\int_{0}^1 x^2dx$$

$$\int_{0}^1 f(x)^2dx \ge 1-a +\frac {a^2} {4}+2a -\frac{a^2}{3} $$

It easy to see that the Quadratic Equation $1-a +\frac {a^2} {4}+2a -\frac{a^2}{3}$ has a maximum value at $a=6$ which make $1-a +\frac {a^2} {4}+2a -\frac{a^2}{3} =4$

So $\displaystyle \int_{0}^1 f(x)^2dx \ge 4$